# Numerically Adding the contents of two dataframes (with different column names)

Tags: python, pandas

A small part of my code is trying to create a computed column in a dataframe by numerically adding two dataframes (varying column names).
However am facing an issue

```
elif any(df.filter(regex="INT : Q2")):
df['ABC'] = ((df.filter(regex="INT : Q2", axis=1)/(PL_EURSGD[1])) + 
                                (df.filter(regex="INT : Q1", axis=1)/(PL_EURSGD[0])))  

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1


df.filter(regex="INT : Q2", axis=1)/(PL_EURSGD[1]) #becomes a dataframe in itself with column name as INT : Q2
(df.filter(regex="INT : Q1", axis=1)/(PL_EURSGD[0]) #becomes another dataframe with column name as INT : Q1
```

Please note all the values are numeric, there is no missing value.
Any suggestions why this is going wrong.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

.values does the trick :)

```
elif any(df.filter(regex="INT : Q2")):
   df['ABC'] = ((df.filter(regex="INT : Q2", axis=1)/(PL_EURSGD[1])).values + 
                            (df.filter(regex="INT : Q1", axis=1)/(PL_EURSGD[0])).values)
```